# When using GridSearchCV with regression tree how to interpret mean_test_score?

Tags: machine-learning, decision-trees, gridsearchcv

I am using GridSearchCV to tune hyperparameters of regression decision tree. When I do, I get mean_test_score but I thought it would return mean MSE since it is a regressor. how to interpret mean_test_score? Is there a way to tweak GridSearchCV so it returns mean MSE?

here is my code

```
tree_reg = GridSearchCV(DecisionTreeRegressor(criterion="mse"), {
    "min_samples_split":[2,3,4],
    "min_samples_leaf":[1,2,3]
}, cv=5, return_train_score=False)

tree_reg.fit(X, y)

pd.DataFrame(tree_reg.cv_results_)
>>> params                   split0_test_score  .... mean_test_score
   {"min_samples_leaf":2,        0.998782             0.9989933
    "min_samples_split":3}

   {"min_samples_leaf":2,        0.998823             0.998930
    "min_samples_split":4}
            ...
```

what does mean_test_score mean?

Answer (score 3):

By default, `GridSearchCV` uses the `score` method of its estimator; see the last paragraph of the `scoring` parameter on [the docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html):

> If None, the estimator’s score method is used.

And [`DecisionTreeRegressor.score`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor.score) (indeed, all/most regressors) uses R^2.

---

In response to your edit: you can specify `scoring='neg_mean_squared_error'`.  But note too that [there's a linear relationship](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/250735/232706) between MSE and R^2, so optimizing either of these are equivalent.